# Full disk sharing on home network on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I would like to connect to a PC disk through a local network, but I keep getting this error (see below).
I am able to connect without problems to a shared folder of that disk, but not to the drive (even though I have shared it in the same way and with the same access permissions).
So I can connect e.g. to `D:\TEMP`, but there is no way to connect to `D:\`

It's a disk which I moved from one PC to another. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Plus, **SHARE** button remains grey (see linked picture). Could it be the reason?

Properties window:

[image]

Comment: Windows 7, same issue. I can share folders, but not disks (and the `Share…` button is grayed out).
1. Disks' contents are accessible via "View network computers and devices" on the same PC I am trying to share them from;
2. Disks are visible over network;
3. "Permission denied" trying to access disks' contents over network.
Tried the answer by @John — no better

Comment: Right click on the drive and see in Properties if you can share it out.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a separate drive, consider the following standard network concepts:

Make sure Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing, and Password protected sharing are all ON.

Restart after you make any changes. Check access to your drive.

If still no access, it may have come from the USERS folder of the other machine and is therefore secure.

You may need to take ownership of the folder and its contents.

[Take Ownership](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-take-ownership-files-and-folders-windows-10)

Open File Explorer.

Browse and find the file or folder you want to have full access.

Right-click it, and select Properties.

Click the Security tab to access the NTFS permissions.

Click the Advanced button.

On the "Advanced Security Settings" page, you need to click the Change link, in the Owner's field.

Click the Advanced button.

On the "Select User or Group" page, click the Find Now button.

From the search result, select your user account, and click OK.

On the "Select User or Group" page, click OK.

Click Apply.

Click OK.

Click OK again.

Click OK one more time to complete this task.